# Javacv CanvasFrame not working as Executable Jar

Tags: java, webcam, javacv

I am using java cv canvas frame in my program for face detection.The code is working fine when     i am running it in eclipse.But the canvas frame is not loading when i am exporting the project as an executable jar file. What is the issue. Is there any configurations to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with opencv dll file.We have to link the dll file present. Create a PATH ENVIRONMENT variable with opencv/build/java/x64 or x86 depending our os and jre version.
Works fine after setting the path.